# How can I succssefully acces an Global Variable from PHP in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Pre Info:
In the PHP I declare a global array ($GLOBALS[]), in it I stow the data for the blade.
On the Blade i have a dropdown. If the dropdown changes, i send via AJAX the value to the Controller.
With the new data i calculate the new information, i want to show on the Blade.

But when I try to get the data in HTML like {{$GLOBALS['MyNumber']}} I only get the initialization value.

```
<?php
.
.
.
$GLOBALS = array(
    'MyNumber' => 1,
    'companyCode' => 0
);

class MyClass extends Controller
{
public function getData(){
   $GLOBALS['companyCode'] = @$_POST['companyCode'];
        if ($GLOBALS['companyCode'] == 902){
            $GLOBALS['MyNumber'] = 100;  //for the example, I set the data fix
        }else{
            $GLOBALS['MyNumber'] = 20; //for the example, I set the data fix
        }
   return response()->json(array('AJAX succses' => $response), 200);

}

.
.
.
```

In HTML i wanna show an dashboard-card with the new data like this:
I have 4 Cards and 7 Tables with data from SQL.

```
@section('page_content')

<div class="card @if($GLOBALS['MyNumber'] >95) dashboard-card-success @else card-anger-@endif" id="bkfI">
                        <div class="dashboard-title">
                            {{ __('bkf_usage') }} {{ today()->year }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="dashboard-content">
                            <div class="dashboard-number" id="bkf_usage">{{$GLOBALS['MyNumber'] }} %</div>
                            <div class="dashboard-description"></div>
                        </div>
</div>
```

But every time i reload the div (so the color can change) the $GLOBALS['MyNumber'] stays on the init of 1.
But the internal use (if $GLOBALS['companyCode']) works fine. How can i solve this issue? Or can you help me to find a work-around?

Maybe pass all the Vars back via ajax to JS and store tem in an JS variable? So i can still access from HTML to them?

Thank You!

Comment: What does "_reload the div_" mean?

Comment: i run this command: $('#bkfI').load(document.URL +  ' #bkfI');

Comment: That is actually an ajax call. You could add the PHP variable value to the data.

Comment: How would an command look like with data?

Comment: The same, you've to update the value on the server when responsing the request. I'm not familiar with Laravel, so I can't tell how exactly to do the update.

Comment: Alright, I will have a closer look at the .load thing. Thank you!